# call to a member function execute() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql

My script containing that error is this:

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare('SELECT libelle,activite,adresse,tel,lat,lng FROM etablissements where type IN ('.$in_list.')');
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($libelle,$activite,$adresse,$tel,$lat,$lng);
```

The php version running on the server (not localhost) is 5.2.17

Comment: Looks like your SQL query is not correct.

Comment: Can you give more details, like the definition of db ?

Comment: Actually this seems to be a php error. What is `$this` refering to ?

Comment: Where do you get the error? What is in `$in_list`?

Comment: I got the error on the second line: `$stmt->execute();` and `$in_list` is a String created after imploding an array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$stmt` is supposed to be an object with the method `execute()`.
Seems like `$this->db->prepare()` is not returning the good result.

If `$this->db` is a [`mysqli()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) object you should [bind the parameters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) like that:

```
if ($stmt = $this->db->prepare('SELECT libelle,activite,adresse,tel,lat,lng FROM etablissements where type IN (?)')) {
  $stmt->bind_param("s", $in_list);
  $stmt->execute();
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanx, BTW, what is the `s` referring to?

Comment: "corresponding variable has type string"

Answer (score 2):

Check the sql you executed,

```
$this->db->prepare('SELECT libelle,activite,adresse,tel,lat,lng FROM etablissements where type IN ('.$in_list.')');
```

does not return a valid statement object.

Comment: `$in_list` in a String created from imploded array.

Comment: Why it's not a valid statement?

Comment: show the result of `var_dump('SELECT libelle,activite,adresse,tel,lat,lng FROM etablissements where type IN ('.$in_list.')')` right before `prepare`, if it is valid sql, check the `prepare` method to see why.

Answer (score 0):

Swap the statement bind and execute and replace result with param, It will work fine

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare('SELECT libelle,activite,adresse,tel,lat,lng FROM etablissements 
where type IN ('.$in_list.')');
$stmt->bind_param($libelle,$activite,$adresse,$tel,$lat,$lng);
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score -2):

Your db object is null. Check if you close the connection too early or somehow you override it to null.